# Retrieving key and value From JSON within JSON

Tags: json

I have a json like

```
 var jsonObject = {
    "key": [
        {
        "key1": "value1",
        "info": "info"},
    {
        "key2": "value2",
        "info": "info"}
    ]
};​
```

I need to retrieve the key and value from this but dynamically, assuming that I don't know the JSON since it will be generated from the web service..

Comment: This is NOT json within json, it's just a typical json. (an object with an array of objects to be exact). You can't process data you have no idea about, look into your webservice API documentation - it has to define the data structure.

Comment: As @Agent_L says this is quite basic JSON. What is your question about it? What language do you need to do the processing in? And what have you already tried?

Comment: ok thats fine but if i dont know "key" or "key1" then is it possible to retrieve both the key and the associated value and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to process the JSON object in JavaScript, you'll need a recursive function like this:

```js
function processObject(jsonObject) {
  for (var property in jsonObject) {
    if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      console.log(property+'='+jsonObject[property]);
      if (typeof (jsonObject[property]) == 'object') {
        processObject(jsonObject[property]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Replace the `console.log` with whatever you want to do to the data.

Comment: but i am stuck with another problem now. what if i want to dispaly only a specific object, for example only "key1" and "info" of first object

Comment: You either simply access it directly like this `jsobObject.key.key2` or you add an `if (property == 'key2')` to the function. If you have more questions, I suggest you update your original question with the code you have a problem with.